# Object Serialization in Java and Android

Tags: java, android

how to write more than one object to  ObjectOutputStream in single response(Objects are not fixed,objects are creating dynamically as per user's request).can i use either Arraylist or Vector for this,please give some sample program.

```
TexxtViews text=new TexxtViews(2, -2, 2, "WELCOME TO CCS");//First Object
ButtonView button=new ButtonView(-2, 2, "OK");//Second Object
ArrayList array=new ArrayList();
array.add(text);
array.add(button);
   OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
   ObjectOutputStream outSt = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
  outSt.writeObject(array);
```

tried this code

Comment: One at a time? What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Serialize the List<Of Serilizable>.